# El nombre del tipo o espacio de nombres SignInManager no se encontró o falta un ensamblado

Tags: webapi

[[image: iEl nombre del tipo o espacio de nombres SignInManager no se encontró o falta un ensamblado.[1]][1]]

La imagen 1 es donde se produce el error, en la segunda es la definición dela interface y la tercera es la clase program donde inyecto registro la interface y el SignInManager, también lo he intentado con el IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor, pero no tenia acceso. Gracias de antemano[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]